# I have some questions about MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql-python

I have installed python 2.7 32bit ,then I installed MySQLdb by MySQL-python-1.2.3.win32-py2.7
it's successful.but when I have a try on it,it has some problems.

I write on the IDLE that:

```
import MySQLdb

conn = MySQLdb.connect (passwd = "chen1991", db = "myddb")  
cursor = conn.cursor ()  
cursor.execute ("SELECT VERSION()")
```

it said I can't connect the databass,the result is followed:

```
   conn = MySQLdb.connect (passwd = "chen1991", db = "myddb")  

File "D:\python安装位置\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
     return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
     File "D:\python安装位置\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 187, in __init__
     super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
     _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost'      (using password: YES)"
```

the password:YES mean that I take the right password,so i don't know what happened.Do I have something wrong when i installed ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to connect to the database as user "ODBC"?

Answer (score 1):

"using password: YES" means that you were using *a* password, but not necessarily that the password matches the username, that the username has connection privileges, or that the username exists. Check your grant tables and try again.

Answer (score 0):

`password: YES` just means that a password was provided. It does not mean it was correct. So you have an authentication problem or your permissions are not set up.

Also, you might need a semicolon at the end of your `SELECT` statement.